# Javascript - proper way of type checking

Tags: javascript

I was suggested to change this:

```
if ( typeof user.account.products !== 'undefined') {}
```

to this:

```
if (user.account && user.account.hasOwnProperty('products'))
```

In second example user.account was added as an extra measure of defence, and it is valid. Now the other part got me curious.

I understand what it does, but still cant wrap my head which one to use.

Comment: The second example gives another layer of checking, which is good. Your first example will throw an error if `user.account` doesn't exist.

Comment: Glad that other answer was deleted, because it was WAY off. Because it had votes that it was useful, just want to clarify that `(typeof a === undefined)` would tell you that the result of `typeof` is `undefined`, which would be a major problem. The correct comparison for `typeof` IS `(typeof a === 'undefined')`. Now, see below for the answer to your question of which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property doesn't exist and you try to get its type or value, you get `undefined`. If you convert `undefined` to a Boolean (which is what an `if/then` statement does with the expression supplied as the condition), you get `false` because certain values are **[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)** and others are **[falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**.

So this is an explicit way of testing for not `undefined`:

```
if ( typeof user.account.products !== 'undefined') {}
```

And, this is an implicit way  of doing the same thing:

```
if (user.account.products)
```

Now your line:

```
if (user.account && user.account.hasOwnProperty('products'))
```

Is more specific than either of these because not only does it test to see if `user.account` exists, but it also tests to see if that object has its own `products` property. If it is that property you intend to use and there is a chance the `user.account` may not exist or that it may, but may not have `products` as a property, then this is the best way to test for it.

But, there are still other ways to do this kind of testing. This:

```
if(account in user && products in user.account)
```

Checks to see if the respective properties exist in their host object without regard to whether the properties are inherited or not.

But, in the end, if it is the `products` property you care about, all you really need is:

```
if(products in user.account);
```

This test will fail if `products` isn't there or it `user.account` isn't valid.

It all depends on how granular you want to test.

Comment: If you check using `hasOwnProperty` won't it report `false` if `products` exists in the prototype, but not on the object itself?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, it will. But as I said in my answer, *"it also tests to see if that object has its **own** products property."*

Comment: Sure. (ps, my comment was a question, not a challenge)

Answer (score 2):

The first check means

```
if ( typeof user.account.products !== 'undefined') {
   // i will execute if products property is defined on user.account
   // even is null or 0
}
```

The second check means (simplified)

```
if (user.account.hasOwnProperty('products')) {
   // i will execute if user.account has a property of "products" even if products property is undefined/null/0 
   // and also i wont be executed if user.account is inherited from something has its own 
   // "products" property but not defined on user.account's prototype (inherited property).

}
```

There is also a third option that you haven't mentioned is this

```
if ('products' in user.account) {
  // i will execute if user.account has a property of
  // "products" even if products property is undefined/null/0
}
```

Comment: I like the third option

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you are asking why using:

```
user.account.hasOwnProperty('products')
```

instead of:

```
user.account.products !== undefined
```

In that case, the two options are valid. With that saying, the new option (hasOwnProperty) is more elegant- Instead of assuming that the property exists, and then check if it is defined, you are asking if the object has this property.